# hf-tikz.sty package installation on mountain lion

Tags: packages, installing, texmaker, mactex, hf-tikz

I want to install LaTeX on Mountain Lion and want to use some highlighting in my text for which I am using `hf-tikz.sty` package. I installed MacTeX and Texmaker on Mountain Lion but the package `hf-tikz` is not installed then I run the `TeXLive` utility to update all the packages but it gives an error that `hf-tikz.sty` package is not installed.

Then i downloaded hf-tikz.sty package from the internet and tried to copy in the directory "`/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base`" but it gives me an error of writing permission.

Can somebody will help me settling out this issue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: Put it in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/hf-tikz/` (creating the necessary folders).

Comment: Open TeX Live Utility and click on the "Packages" tab. Wait a few seconds for everything to load. Then, in the "Filter" dialog box, type "hf-tikz". In the status column, it will either say "installed" or "not installed". If it says "not installed", control-click on that package and click "Install selected packages". It should work then. Failing that, you can put the `hf-tikz` file(s) you downloaded in a folder down the following path: `/Users/<your username>/Library/texmf/tex`

Comment: Hi, There is no texmf directory under the Library directory on my system. There are only TexShop and Texwork directory. Any Help?

Comment: @Madu The `~` refers to your Home. So something like `/Users/Madu/Library/texmf`. However, `hf-tikz` is in TeX Live, now. If you run TeX Live Utility and update the distribution, you'll get it without needing manual installation.

Comment: This comes down to the 'installing locally' question we get quite a bit.